# Not getting the explanation result on running Explain API in ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ES version 7.9.2 and trying to run the Explain API but the response does not return any explanation result, what could be the reason?

Here's the curl I tried

```
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:9200/test/default/_search?explain=' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 1bd83933-74cd-465d-87da-65bba4efcaad' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -d '{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "data.createdAtEpoch": {
                            "from": 1589740200000,
                            "to": 1621318182305,
                            "include_lower": true,
                            "include_upper": true,
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "data.A": [
                                        "testA"
                                    ],
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "terms": {
                                    "data.B": [
                                        "testB1",
                                        "testB2",
                                        "testB3"
                                    ],
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                        "boost": 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "version": true,
    "aggregations": {
        "data.payload.C": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "data.payload.C",
                "size": 300000,
                "min_doc_count": 1,
                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                "order": [
                    {
                        "_count": "desc"
                    },
                    {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I've also tried passing `"explain":true` in the body and the approach here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html. However, I get only the following result:

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 0,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "data.payload.C": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

There is no `explanation`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, you can [use](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html)

```
GET /<index-name/_explain/<id>
```

This will return  `"matched": false` in the search result, if the document having `id` did not match with the query. And if the document matches, then the score explanation (for that matched document) will come in the result.

In the second case, When you are using `explain=true`, this should return the explanation of the score of all the **matching documents**. But, you are not getting any matched results (as the `hits[]` array is empty), I think that none of the documents has matched your query due to which explain API also didn't return any result.

Comment: Yes, although the individual id explain did not work for me, I was indeed not getting explanation because of hits[]. Thanks!